# Used cut to create groups for a variable, how would I use it in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I used the `cut` function to create bins for a variable and the result was this:

```
var <- structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("[0,3]", 
"(3,40]", "(40,738]"), class = "factor")
```

But how would I use this in ggpplot? I am unclear what to do since there's not a  dataframe anymore.

```
plot(var)
```

Basically I want to recreate the above histogram but in ggplot.

Here's a reproducible version:

```
qv <- round(quantile(iris$Sepal.length))
d <- cut(iris$Sepal.length, qv[!duplicated(qv)], include.lowest=TRUE)
```

Comment: Have you tried adding this variable to the original dataset and then making a bar plot?  Or put its own data.frame prior to plotting?

Comment: @aosmith oh interesting, but at that point would it be a bar plot?

Comment: It would be - and the plot you're trying to recreate is a bar plot too. Your `plot(var)` is running `barplot(table(var))` under the hood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `ggplot2` manual:

> geom_bar() makes the height of the bar proportional to the number of
> cases in each group

You can use the following code:

```
ggplot2::ggplot(data = data.frame(var = var)) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=var))
```

which will produce output equivalent to base R.